# VBA Change size when is pasting

Tags: vba, copy-paste, font-size

I'm trying to copy info from one file and paste to another two files, but when it pastes, it changes the font size. im having this problem with only one of the files (Compiled data). I'm still learning VBA so I'm probably missing something...

```
Sub Sites()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim InputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputFile As Workbook
Dim FormulasFile As Workbook
Dim Inputpath As String
Dim Outputpath As String
Dim Formulaspath As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Set path for files
fileInputpath = "C:\Users\Workbooks\"
Outputpath = "C:\Users\Workbooks\"
Formulaspath = "C:\Users\Workbooks\"

'Open workbooks first
Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(Inputpath & "C:\Users\Workbooks\Weekly data.xlsx")
Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(Outputpath & "Compiled data.xlsx")
Set FormulasFile = Workbooks.Open(Formulaspath & "Formulas Pivot data.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False)

'Now, copy what you want from InputFile and paste to OutputFile/FormulasFile worksheet
With InputFile.Sheets("Report")
lRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
.Range("C3:O" & lRow).Copy OutputFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(OutputFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

'****This part is not working
For Each ws In Worksheets
With ws
.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
.Cells.Font.Size = 9
End With
Next ws

End With

'this part is working fine
With InputFile.Sheets("Report")
lRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
.Range("C3:O" & lRow).Copy FormulasFile.Sheets("Site").Cells(FormulasFile.Sheets("Site").Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

For Each ws In Worksheets
With ws
.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
.Cells.Font.Size = 9
End With
Next ws

End With

'Close all files without display alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
InputFile.Close False
OutputFile.Close True
FormulasFile.Close True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @ABF in the not working part, make sure that you assign the correct workbook. So instead of "For Each ws In Worksheets" make it "For Each ws In Workbook.Worksheets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend enabling `Option Explicit` this helps you find any mistypes easier in your code. All this does is throw out an error 'Variable Not Defined' when you try to run your code as `FileInputpath` was not used any where in your code. When you get your code working without errors I recommend post in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as they can help more with working code but isn't quite up to expectation (or you feel could be written better)

The reason your code isn't working is likely because `Worksheets` will work off the `ActiveWorkbook` unless defined otherwise. Which going by your code would be the 'Formulas Pivot data.xlsx' file. The below should hopefully help, ask if you need any clarity on anything

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sites()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim InputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputFile As Workbook
Dim FormulasFile As Workbook
Dim Inputpath As String
Dim Outputpath As String
Dim Formulaspath As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Set path for files
Inputpath = "C:\Users\Workbooks\"
Outputpath = "C:\Users\Workbooks\"
Formulaspath = "C:\Users\Workbooks\"

'Open workbooks first
Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(Inputpath & "Weekly data.xlsx")
Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(Outputpath & "Compiled data.xlsx")
Set FormulasFile = Workbooks.Open(Formulaspath & "Formulas Pivot data.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False)

'Now, copy what you want from InputFile and paste to OutputFile/FormulasFile worksheet
With InputFile.Sheets("Report")
    lRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    .Range("C3:O" & lRow).Copy OutputFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(OutputFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    '****This part is not working
    For Each ws In OutputFile.Worksheets
        With ws
            .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .Cells.Font.Size = 9
        End With
    Next ws
    
End With

'this part is working fine
With InputFile.Sheets("Report")
    lRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    .Range("C3:O" & lRow).Copy FormulasFile.Sheets("Site").Cells(FormulasFile.Sheets("Site").Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    For Each ws In FormulasFile.Worksheets
        With ws
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 9
        End With
    Next ws
    
End With

'Close all files without display alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
InputFile.Close False
OutputFile.Close True
FormulasFile.Close True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: ow, thank so much for the explanation, you are amazing, it works perfectly!